# Optimisation of vocabulary learning

Tags: words, kanji, learning

I have a question related to the creation of a rationalised list of vocabulary working in pairs with kanji learning. If one wants to learn Japanese, at some point there is no other choice than learning big lists of vocabulary, simply because there is not much to relate to the the learner's mother-tongue (at least if one's native language is not Chinese). We also encounter in most kanji books lists of vocabulary associated to each kanji, and the average number of words related to one kanji varies from books (say **4** to **20**). Therefore I asked myself what would be the optimal number of words that shall be actually used.

So we have our list of ***N*** kanji, and for all ***i* = 1, ... , *N***, let ***m***<sub>*i*</sub> the number of words associated the kanji number ***i***. Now one should be careful to make a list without repetitions, but at the same time minimising the average of numbers associated to each kanji. So we have arranged all words, by relating each to only one kanji, such that the mean

[image]

is minimal (this condition will appear clearly later). Then we look for an integer ***n*** corresponding to the number of words we learn per kanji, such that the expectation of knowing an arbitrary word is high, but ***n*** is not too high either (for example, if one has to learn **100** words per kanji, this system does not work). Therefore, for a word ***w*** associated to the kanji ***i*** (let us denote ***A***<sub>*i*</sub> the set of words associated to the kanji ***i***), the probability to know the word is

[image]

with obvious abuse of notations. Therefore

[image]

and one would know approximately ***n***/***m̅*** of the vocabulary. And ***n*** is approximately equal to the average ***m̅***, which explains why we had to minimise this quantity.

Therefore my question is two-sided : what is the minimal value of ***m̅***? Indeed, if we compare a simple kanji like 人 which has more than **2000** matches and some rare kanji with one or two occurrences, it is not *a priori* obvious if this quantity (***m̅***) is large (**>100** say) or not. I should add that obviously if we consider all words in Japanese language, this system is unrealistic, but for smaller ambitions, it could actually be useful if the number ***m̅*** is not too large. One could for example think about the kanji and vocabulary lists for standardized international tests.

Comment: We don't have MathJax here, I'm afraid.  Here is an image of what the code above looks like rendered on MO: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjYog.png

Comment: The inherent flaw is that the majority of the words in the dictionary, or those word lists are actually useful.  I argue that most are not.  Very hard to enumerate any type of useful value.

Comment: First time I ever seen math used to learn a language.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly, but how many kanji you must learn before learning 挨 and 拶, effectively only used in Japanese in a word 挨拶, which is in turn among commonest word?

Comment: @GoBusto : thanks for the edition, too bad there is not MathJax here.@ broccoli forest : I don't know, because I think that these kanji are not even part of the official 2141 kanji list. So these kanji are to be learn after the official list. And once someone get to this level, it is possible to read about any text (well at least newspapers...) and learn vocabulary in a more natural way than learning big lists.

Comment: @Paul-Benjamin I've slowly been understanding your question and realizing that my previous comment is kind of irrelevant. But a trivia is that the two kanji are actually _inside_ the joyo kanji list because of the word.

Comment: @broccoliforest : Indeed, they are inside, but in this framework, as they are only linked to one word, it does not affect the value m̅  we are looking for. I am sorry if I was not clear enough, this is my first question on this stackexchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've long been wanting to create a list of *kanji* (say, all *jōyō kanji*) ordered by weight, where the weight is determined by the frequency of the *kanji* itself and by the weight of all those *kanji* in which this *kanji* appears as a radical. (Also see the end of this post.)

If the average person has a vocabulary of [at least 30,000 words](http://www.kecl.ntt.co.jp/icl/lirg/resources/goitokusei/goi-test.html), a list of words covering a larger range (say 95%) of people is obviously much larger than this. Maybe more like 50,000–70,000.

Even though a good portion of words has no (or only obsolete) *kanji* representations, it seems impractical to try to create a reasonably complete vocabulary list of 50,000 words, or even an "average" list of 30,000. (This would require around 15–25 words per *kanji*.)

Still, you could choose a number (say 5) and create a list of 10,000 words (*kanji*-by-*kanji* in the order their "weights") by choosing the five most common words containing a particular *kanji*, eliminating words that you chose previously.

This seems to be a reasonable way to learn *kanji*, as well as creating vocabulary lists that are more tuned to a gradually increasing knowledge of *kanji*. (Otherwise pure frequency lists would do the job.)

I also think it gives you what you want, because the resulting vocabulary list of 10,000 words is essentially just a reordering of the same list ordered by frequency. (This is not entirely true, as there are extremely rare *kanji*, like 訃 (least frequent *kanji* in BCCWJ), which probably don't have 5 words in the top 10,000 words containing this *kanji*. It's basically a reordering with holes on those words whose *kanji* already have been represented at least 5 times in the list by more frequent words with the holes having been patched by less frequent words with *kanji* who haven't been represented.)

---

There are several ways in which the weights could be adapted to account for more than just frequency:

1. One could also take into account the stage at which individual *kanji* are taught in Japanese schools in order to optimize the list not only for usage (in newspapers/books), but also exposure in existing learning materials, which are mostly based on the [*kyōiku kanji*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%A6%E5%B9%B4%E5%88%A5%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E9%85%8D%E5%BD%93%E8%A1%A8).
2. I would also like to associate to each *kanji* all *kanji* which contain the same phonetic component, even if the *on'yomi* is slightly different, like 番 幡 or 読 続. One could also consider that such *kanji* are easier to learn in groups and thus allow for the weights to be increased.
3. One might also give a small preference to pictographs over ideographs etc.

(I have started this and if I were only half as tech-savvy as the people here on Stack Exchange, I might have finished already.)

Comment: @ Earthliŋ : Thank you very much for this interesting and thourough answer. But how would you actually create this list? I don't know where to find this kind of data and to treat it efficiently.

Comment: Frequency data in available in corpora, for example the Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/. Reliable information of phonetic components or classification into pictographs/ideographs/etc. would probably have to be taken from dictionaries. The list of *kyōiku kanji* I have linked in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think there is still substantial work to do but I have now enough information about my question to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think the >= sign should be reversed, your lower bound is an upper bound.

I think m̅ is fixed and therefore trivially minimal.

It is trivially possible (but practically completely infeasible) to construct a right-uniqe word->kanji mapping by simply choosing exactly 1 Kanji for every distinct word that appears in the total list. Minimizing m̅ is equivalent to minimizing N*m̅, which is simply the sum of all mj (the number of distinct words considered in total, as the reverse kanji->word mapping is injective), which trivially has the same value for each possibly such mapping. Therefore m̅ is simply the sum of all distinct words in the total list divided by N.

I think what you want to minimize is actually n, while still covering a satisfactory fraction of all words? In any case, the sane solution, imo, would be to simply learn word lists directly and take the Kanji as they come for every such word. In my experience, this is a much more productive approach than focusing on, or even considering directly, "readings" or "keywords".